# Haskell XMLRPC server executing dynamically generated functions

Tags: haskell, xml-rpc

I have a Haskell RPCXML (HaXR) server process, run with GHC, that needs to execute any function that it's passed. These functions will all be defined at runtime so the compiled server won't know about them.

Is there a way to load a function definition at runtime? A method that avoids disk IO is preferable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint) seems to be popular these days.

Although to load a function definition I think you will either have to put it into a module, or re-interpret it every time you use it.